# Error occurring , while install magento on win7

Tags: magento, windows-7, xampp

I am getting error , "There has been an error processing your request" when I type

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php
```

in firefox. I am unable to install magento in windows 7.
When , i look this error in magento/var/report directory , it gives detail about error

"SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" . 
Please help me in this matter.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.0 and xampp 1.7.7 . I tried a lot to solve this error.

Comment: "I tried a lot"... what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `/app/etc/local.xml` to ensure that the correct password for your MySQL is set.

Comment: Again , there is a problem in admin panel.
when I open admin panel , it asks username and password.
But , during installation of magento , it doesn't ask me about that.
so , here what username and password should I enter?

Comment: Thank you so much Roscius , but it didn't help me much.I m still there where i was before this answer.

Comment: Your question is really a new question, sounds like you need to investigate resetting the admin password, it should have been set during installation.  I'd suggest opening a new question if you're still experiencing problems.

Comment: when I installed magento on winXP 2-3 months earlier using wamp server.Everything was executing fine . It asked me to create admin username and password.Installation took place in 3-4 steps.But , in win7 I just typed 
http://localhost/magento/index.php 
and it took 3-4 min and whole installation completed in just 1 step.
And magento didn't ask me about admin username and password.

And after googling alot and also u'r hyperlink , i tried to entered value manually , but now it gives me error "Access denied."